# Signing an existing unsigned apk in Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

Is there a way in Gradle to sign an already existing, unsigned apk? We want to produce the unsigned artifact, make a copy of it, sign one with the debug cert, and the other with the release cert. The reason we want to do it this way is to avoid having to build the code multiple times (for the debug and release apks). Is something like this possible?

Comment: If you guys are using Android Studio, it might not be that cumbersome. Adding a link for ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: We aren't using Android Studio. We have our android build set up as a subproject in our Gradle build system.